# Gradle sync is failing with "Could not resolve dependency" errors

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have the following setup:

- Android Studio 2021.3.1
- gradle: 7.4

Root level build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1'
        classpath 'com.github.spotbugs:spotbugs-gradle-plugin:4.7.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Module level build.gradle:

```
import com.github.spotbugs.snom.SpotBugsTask

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
    id 'checkstyle'
    id 'com.github.spotbugs'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    google()
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}

apply from: "publisher.gradle"

<...>

dependencies {
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.0.0')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:6.1.2'
    implementation 'com.github.AppIntro:AppIntro:6.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database'
    implementation 'com.github.sematext:sematext-logsene-android:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.mik3y:usb-serial-for-android:3.4.6'
}
```

And while doing **gradle sync** in Android Studio, I come accross with the following errors:
[image: Dependency failure]

First error in text:

```
:projectName:main: Could not resolve androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1.
Required by:
    project :projectName

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

As you see above, I've declared repositories which contain these dependencies, and I know for sure that these versions exist.

I have already tried: Clearing gradle caches, clearing Android Studio caches and restart, switch to another network, switching off my firewall - nothing helps. And I see that gradle has successfully resolved some dependencies from the full list (for example, materialdrawer and firebase).

Everything was working some time ago - I haven't opened the project since 2-3 months, and it was working before. And now it's not, and I cannot understand why. Could someone please help me?

Ah, and by the way, "gradle clean", then "gradle build", which uses same dependencies, is finishing successfully, really assembling the build, on the same instance of Android Studio on the same laptop, only "gradle sync" is failing. Which makes it really unclear for me what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

In your root level gradle, maybe try adding

```
maven {
  url = uri("https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/")
}
```

So overview

```
buildscript {
    val kotlinVersion = "1.7.20"
    repositories {
        maven {
            url = uri("https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/")
        }
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

Note: My Gradle is in the kts format so it might be different on your end.

Comment: Thank you, but that didn't help.

Comment: @Roher have you updated to the latest Android Studio and gradle version?

Comment: Yes, I have done it the day before yesterday - I have mentioned the versions at the beginning of my question.

Comment: The solution worked for me, thank you. Why did this help and why is there nothing official from google?

Comment: @Roher sorry, I didn't see the versions. Remove jitpack?

Comment: @Noiling yeah, I remember I have to search the depths of the internet for this solution.

Comment: I cannot remove it, as some depencies, such as: 'com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:6.1.2', 'com.github.AppIntro:AppIntro:6.2.0', 'com.github.sematext:sematext-logsene-android:3.2.0', 'com.github.mik3y:usb-serial-for-android:3.4.6' come from that repository.

Comment: I opened an issue as it seems this has something to do with Android Studio Dolphin. I now get "Unresolved class" inside the manifest, although I can start the app inside the emulator. This is the link: https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/254891042

Comment: Okay thanks for the follow up, can anyone confirm if this was working on previous AS versions?

Comment: I deleted the whole SDK folder and updated to AS Electric Eel, which finally fixed all the issues. So yes, I think it had something to do with AS Dolphin.

Comment: Thank you @Noiling, updating to AS Electic Eel (without deleting SDK folder) has solved the problem for me too!

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a similar issue with the "facebook-login" dependency caused by "androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0".

Disabling the Jetifier in **gradle.properties** fixed it.

```
android.enableJetifier=false
```